# Dummy variables for time series

Tags: r, time-series, categorical-data, arima

I'm a new user on R. I'm stuck on my times series research currently with the some questions. Not sure anyone can help me.

1. Dummy variable. 
   I wanted to add more than 1 dummy variable in the model. But, I realized that the results unchanged after I put additional dummy variables. I have no idea why this happens. I provided my R code as below. Hopefully someone can advise me.

   R-Code:

   ```
   xreg <- cbind(CNY=model.matrix(~as.factor(daily.2yrd$CNY)),HRP=daily.2yrd$HRP,Deepa=daily.2yrd$Deepa,Xmas=daily.2yrd$Xmas)
   viewData(xreg)

   daily_forecast.fit <- Arima(daily.2yrd$Total_Visitor,order=c(7,0,7),seasonal=c(0,1,0),lambda=round(BoxCox.lambda(daily_visitor.ts,lower=0),4), xreg=xreg)
   daily_forecast.fit
   ```
2. Define dummy variable.
   How can I define my dummy variable if the outlier is lower value? If I define as "Dummy 1", my result will skew to higher point which I think is wrong. Any comments?

   Example:

   ```
   ID      Sales      Dummy 1
   1       1800        0
   2       2000        0
   3       1500        0
   4        500        1
   5       1800        0
   6       1600        0
   ```